# iterating over values in a block

Tags: ruby

I use blocks to create values like so

```
some_block = BlockClass.new {|b|
  b.one   = 1
  b.two   = 2
  b.three = 3
}
```

Here is `BlockClass`

```
class BlockClass
  attr_accessor :one
  attr_accessor :two
  attr_accessor :three
  def initialize
    yield self if block_given?
  end
end
```

I need a way to iterate over `some_block`, and print all the value in the block without having to do

```
puts some_block.one
puts some_block.two
puts some_block.three
```

Is there a way to iterate over the values in the block?

Comment: Can you show `BlockClass`?

Comment: @August I made an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `b` parameter in the block is nil, so you will get a

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `one=' for nil:NilClass`
```

To fix this, you can change `yield if block_given?` to `yield(self) if block_given?`, which will pass `self` as the first parameter to the block.

If you want the `b.one = ..., b.two = ...` syntax, you should use an [`OpenStruct`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html):

```
require 'ostruct'
class BlockClass < OpenStruct
  def initialize
    super
    yield(self) if block_given?
  end
end
```

You can get a dump of the internal `Hash` by calling `marshal_dump`:

```
some_block = BlockClass.new {|b|
  b.one   = 1
  b.two   = 2
  b.three = 3
}

some_block.marshal_dump # => {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}
```

You can then iterate over the values:

```
some_block.marshal_dump.each_pair do |k, v|
  puts "the value of #{k} is #{v}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your block takes 1 parameter, `b`, but your yield statement doesn't pass anything in. Perhaps you mean, `yield self if block_given?`?

Also, if you want to "iterate", you'll need an enumerable collection of something, like an `Array` or `Hash`. As is, `one`, `two`, and `three` are totally unrelated accessors to your `BlockClass`.

You *could* iterate over all methods of `BlockClass`:

```
(some_block.methods).each do |method_name|
  puts some_block.send(method_name)
end
```

But that doesn't sound like what you're looking for. Perhaps [Initialize a Ruby class from an arbitrary hash, but only keys with matching accessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676200/listing-the-accessors-in-a-ruby-class) might help?

Comment: essentially what I want is instead of writing "puts some_block.one, puts some_block.two, puts some_block.three, etc..." I could iterate over the block and print it's values.  Imagine you had a block with 100 of those values, you wouldn't want to put 100 puts statements

Comment: Stop saying "iterating over the block"!  A block isn't even an object, so it can't have attributes.